# Angular How to change navmenu header based on route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on a Dashboard layout in my current project with Angular 4+.

When the user navigates between the different sections of the app I need the navmenu header title to update to reflect the current section of the app.

[image]

As an example when the user visits settings "Page Title" should change to "Settings"

[image]

The project is based on the .net core 2 Angular template
Below is the code I have to makeup the app routing as well as the dashboard routing.

**navigation.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
    private titleSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Page Title");
    currentTitle = this.titleSource.asObservable();

    constructor() {
    }

    changeTitle(title: string) {
        this.titleSource.next(title);
    }
}
```

**app-routing.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.shared**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { DashboardModule } from "./components/dashboard/dashboard.module";

import { UtilsModule } from "./components/shared/shared.module";
//app components
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';

import { NavigationService } from "./services/navigation.service";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,

    ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        DashboardModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        DevExtremeModule,
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [NavigationService]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

**dashboard-routing.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard.component";
import { SettingsProfileComponent } from "./settings/settingsProfile/settings.profile.component";
import { SettingsEmailComponent } from "./settings/settingsEmail/settings.email.component";
import { UsersListComponent } from "./users/users.list.component";

export const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [{
            path: 'settings',
            data: { title: 'Settings' },

            children: [{
                path: 'profile',
                component: SettingsProfileComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'email',
                component: SettingsEmailComponent
            }]
        }, {
                path: 'users',
                data: { title: 'Users' },
                children: [{
                    path: '',
                    component: UsersListComponent
                }]
        }]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

**dashboard.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UtilsModule } from "../shared/shared.module";

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from "./dashboard-routing.module";

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { SettingsProfileComponent } from "./settings/settingsProfile/settings.profile.component";
import { SettingsEmailComponent } from "./settings/settingsEmail/settings.email.component";
import { UsersListComponent } from "./users/users.list.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        UtilsModule,
        DashboardRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        SettingsProfileComponent,
        SettingsEmailComponent,
        UsersListComponent,
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class DashboardModule {
}
```

I am trying to avoid having a OnInit in each component. Is it possible to do this only in the routing? The project is early on so if there are any other recommendations on how to accomplish this we are open to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option may be a route guard/route resolver. You could add a guard/resolver to each route and have it read your data property.

Here is an example resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { IMovie } from './movie';
import { MovieService } from './movie.service';

@Injectable()
export class MovieResolver implements Resolve<IMovie> {

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService,
                private navigationService: NavigationService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        const title = route.data['title'];
        this.navigationService.changeTitle(title);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Something like the above.

Comment: @gboh - go with this one for sure if you clone the process in multiple components ... otherwise, I would say that my answer is easier to implement for beginner and is good enough to serve your purpose in single component. DeborahK's solution is more efficient in larger scale, to make mime work at larger scale, you would probably have to turn it in some kind of service, otherwise you would end up with repeated code in multiple components.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to handle this. One possible solution is to listen to router events and based on them decide about what content should be displayed.

This approach would reguire importing navigation state first, for example, when route change ended. Like this:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```

then you need to subscirbe to that, for example like this.

```
constructor ( private router:  Router ) {
router.events.subscribe( (event) => ( event instanceof NavigationEnd ) && this.handleRouteChange() )
```

}

Once you are able to detect change in navigation you can see, what route it is and based on that make further deccisions. For example like this:

```
  handleRouteChange = () => {
    if (this.router.url.includes('some_key_part_of_url') {
     do what ever you want to do with your content...
    }
  };
```

You do not necessarily analyse the actual content of the url, you may decide on other router properties. Please, read [the docs on router](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Comment: To add to this, you could change the final code above to user your `data` property.