# Angular Router change URL before continuing

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an application where I need to check, before the route change, if there is an url segment on the localstorage and, if necessary, update the URL.

But I want to do it BEFORE the route changes.

Currently I'm trying to use NavigationStart event to do this url update but I can see the url is changing breefly before the update is done. Like this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // Here I update the url if necessary
    }
});
```

But on the end route there is an automatic call to the server (done on OnInit) and I can see this call being made with the URL before the update.

Is there a way the prevent the route change before I finish my checking process?

Comment: you can use router guard for that, it's the best solution

Comment: this post might give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446775/angular-how-to-change-navmenu-header-based-on-route/48446970#48446970

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data